# Azure Kubernetes Services - when it is required to set AKS Service Principle on other Azure Resources in order to have connection?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, service-principal

By default when creating an AKS cluster a service principal is being created for that cluster.

Then that Service Principal can be set on the level of some other Azure Resource (VM?) in order for them to be able to establish a network connection and for them to be able to communicate (except of of course general network settings)

I am really not sure and can not understand when this is required and when not. If for example I have db on VM level do I need to grant the AKS service principal access to the VM to be able to communicate with it through the network or not?

Can someone provide me some guidance for this, and not general documentation. When this is required to be used/set on the level of those other Azure resources and when it is not?
I cannot find proper explanation for this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding your question about the DB**, you do not need to give the service principal any access to that VM. Given that the Database runs outside of Kubernetes does not need to access that VM in any way. The database could even be in a different data center or hosted on another cloud provider entirely, applications running inside kubernetes will still be able to communicate with it as long as the traffic is allowed by firewalls etc.

I know you did not ask for generic documentation, but the documentation on [Kubernetes Service Principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal) puts it well:

> To interact with Azure APIs, an AKS cluster requires either an Azure
> Active Directory (AD) service principal or a managed identity. A
> service principal or managed identity is needed to dynamically create
> and manage other Azure resources such as an Azure load balancer or
> container registry (ACR).

In other words, the Service principal is the identity that the Kubernetes cluster authenticates with when it interacts with other Azure resources such as:

- [Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#azure-container-registry): The images that the containers are created from must come from somehwere. If you are storing your custom images in a private registry the cluster must be authorized to pull images from the registry. If the private registry is an Azure container registry the service principal must be authorized for those operations
- [Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#networking): Kubernetes must be able to dynamically configure routetables and to register external IP's for services in a loadbalancer. Again, the service principal is used as identity so it must be authorized
- [Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#storage): To access disk resources and mount them into pods
- [Azure Container instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#azure-container-instances): In case you are using the virtual kubelet to dynamically add compute resources to your cluster Kubernetes must be allow to manage containers on ACI.

To [delegate access to other Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#delegate-access-to-other-azure-resources) you can use the azure cli to assign a role to a an assignee on a certain scope:

```
az role assignment create --assignee <appId> --scope <resourceScope> --role Contributor
```

Here is [a detailed list of all cluster identity permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity#aks-cluster-identity-permissions) in use

Comment: Thank for this great and very detailed explanation. Now I understand it is more for all the Azure APIs usage.
But when you say that for Networking and Storage it must use service principal - it does not mean that I need to assign it manually, it means it will just leverage already existing service principal in order to authentication when communicating with those Azure resources... correct?

Comment: That totally depends on your use case. If you are using the default settings and basic networking you should be good without manually assigning any permissions to the service principal. On the other hand, if you for example are using advanced networking and the subnets and public IP addresses are in another resource group you will need to assign the  Network contributor role to that subnet. Same principle applies for disk resources, or if you have an Azure container registry you would like to connect to,

Comment: Thanks daniel I marked that as answer. I will be using CNI. Most probably the same VN, RG but different Subnet. What in that case - should I have to assign service principal to that other subnet where my VMs outside the AKS are? That is why I am confused -where are those "rules" defined, so I could know if I should handle it or its been taken care automatically...

Comment: No, you will need to assign the Network Contributor role to the subnet where the **VM's inside the Kubernetes cluster is (i.e the nodes where the containers are deployed)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal#networking

Comment: please sorry but just to clarify one thing - if I create AKS cluster with  the default selected vn/subnet or with existing vn/subnet why the role is not being automatically assigned to that vn/subnet? I can not understand that.. ofc if you creating AKS cluster and you reference some subnet or create a new one - it does not seem logical for that cluster NOT to have access to that subnet since you are creating for that vnet (why to assign afterwards) I cannot understand why this delegation of the service principal is not being delegated automatically??? can you please explain me this..:( thanks

Comment: Please also note that the "default settings" and advanced networking with an existing Vnet are two different scenarios that behave differently in this regard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-virtual-networks

When you are using advanced networking where you are using an existing virtual network and subnet or public IP addresses in another resource group the permissions are not assigned automatically.  I guess that is how MS designed it.